# How were house churches overseen by elders?

Tags: local-church, early-church, house-church

Acts 14:23

> When they had appointed elders for them in every church, having prayed with fasting, they entrusted them to the Lord in whom they had believed.

It seemed expected/the norm for each church to have elders overseeing them.

Romans 16:5

> also greet the church that is in their house. Greet Epaenetus, my beloved, who is the first convert to Christ from Asia.

It seems that churches gathered in houses for worship.

If the following assumptions are also true:

- Elders must be old enough and spiritually qualified men.
- There must be a plurality of elders to oversee a church.
- Most churches (if not all) located in Antioch, Berea, Colossae, Corinth, Crete, Ephesus, Galatia, Jerusalem, Philippi, Rome, Thessalonica, Troas... gathered in houses.
- Most letters of Paul (if not all) addressed a network/group of house churches (as opposed to a single large congregation) of the city (Rome, Corinth, Galatia, Ephesus, Philippi, Colossae, and Thessalonica) after which the letter was named.
- House churches were small groups of people (10-30 people per house?) divided by sometimes three generations of people (children, parents, grandparents), then divided by two genders.

Then, how could any house church find elders among them considering the size and the demographic distribution of the church?

Answer (score 1):

Several of the OP's assumptions are questionable, especially #2, #4, 5
#5, because there is little or no evidence.  However, I will concentrate on the meaning of the pertinent verb, χειροτονέω (cheirotoneó) which occurs just twice, Acts 14:23, 2 Cor 8:19.  Its meaning is correctly given here >> https://biblehub.com/greek/5500.htm as:

> **xeirotonéō** literally means, "'I stretch out the hand,' thus expressing agreement with a motion, then, 'I elect by show of hands'
> [of popular vote]), 'I elect' " (Souter); properly, 'to vote by
> stretching out the hand' (practised in the assembly, so Athenian,
> Lucian, Plutarch)" (Abbott-Smith).]

This was the common method of voting in the Greek assemblies and the senate.

In modern terms this simply means to elect by a show of raised hands.  Thus, it appears that churches elected their elders.

Comment: The linked definition starts with: "5500 xeirotonéō – properly, stretch out the hands to commission (send forth)." I may be misunderstanding the reference - are there two possibilities? 1. to commission 2. to elect by show of hands

Comment: @DavidD - the word was used in the senate as a show of hands when voting.

Comment: @Dottard Never noticed that, thank you.